# Get IP with subnet mask for use with AWS EC2 SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ip, ip-address

When setting up an EC2 instance AWS Console has a useful feature to find your current IP address complete with subnet mask for whitelisting. Here is the UI I'm sure we have all seen.

[image]

This is convenient when you are setting it up but if you need to white list a remote DEV's home WIFI or you are using cloudformation it is not longer convenient to get the IP address this way.

So, is there a convenient way to print out your IP address complete with the subnet mask (/) from your terminal? I have not found one.

Comment: The network mask for a single host is /32. At the command line, you can get what appears to be your public IP address in many ways, including: "wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -" (remove the quotes).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on **linux or mac** it's fairly simple to do a `ip addr show` or assign to a variable with `IP_ADDR=$(ip addr show)`.

On windows, there's a PowerShell module you can use.

`Invoke-WebRequest ifconfig.me/ip`

though that prints out more than just the IP, you can always parse it.

Comment: The address this will capture will usually be a private, internal IP address from the LAN, not useful in security group rules.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized I did not understand CIDR notation and subnet masking.

Basically AWS requires CIDR notation and CIDR notation allows you to specify a range of addresses. It works out that the `/32` means a range of 0 so the address is everything to the left of the /.

So, to whitelist a single IP you say `myIP/32`

Comment: The source input field hints that you may provide a "CIDR, IP or Security Group" yet it actually does not allow an IP. In fact, it allows a CIDR, a Security Group, or a Prefix List ID, so the hint is doubly wrong. I think the function is wrong too - it should allow a single IP address and you should not have to specify this as a /32 host route.

Comment: Yeah, as someone new to networking this did not help my learning process.